# change to use 2 defined variables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to change this..

```
variable myref REFCURSOR
begin
  OPEN :myref FOR 
    select sysdate,12345 xid from dual
      union all
    select sysdate,67890 xid from dual;
end;
/
print myref
```

to use 2 defined variables for the xid column (12345 and 67890).  I just can't seem to get the syntax to work with the above code.

Something like this

```
declare 
myNum1 NUMBER:=12345
myNum2 NUMBER:=67890

variable myref REFCURSOR
begin
  OPEN :myref FOR 
    select sysdate,|| myNum1 || xid from dual
      union all
    select sysdate,|| myNum2 || xid from dual;
end;
/
print myref
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VARIABLE declaration has to take place outside the PL/SQL block since it is a SQL*Plus command to create a substitution variable.  The numeric variables can be declared in the PL/SQL block and referenced just like any other PL/SQL variable

```
SQL> variable myref REFCURSOR
SQL> declare
  2    myNum1 number := 12345;
  3    myNum2 number := 67890;
  4  begin
  5    open :myref
  6     for
  7     select sysdate, myNum1 xid from dual
  8     union all
  9     select sysdate, myNum2 from dual;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print myref;

SYSDATE          XID
--------- ----------
08-FEB-11      12345
08-FEB-11      67890
```

Comment: @user584583 - Changed my answer to reflect the additional information.

Comment: I see where I was confused now.  Thanks Justin!